# Setting Wordpress-language programmatically in version 4+

Tags: internationalization, wordpress, buddypress

I developed my own huge WP-plugin and localized it in 3 languages. It works great when switching the language from wp-admin->settings, but it does not switch language when I switch the language per code like this:

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'wpse_52419_change_language' );
function wpse_52419_change_language( $locale ){
   return 'fr_FR';
}
```

The rest of the site however is switching according to this code.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my fault was simpel: I included the load_plugin_textdomain-command too early.

Just as a note, maybe it will help someone, I now did the following which works like a charm:

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'slople_change_language' );
function slople_change_language( $locale )
{
    $lang = 'en';
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        //get parameter is the most important factor
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    }else if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
        //cookie is the 2nd most important factor
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }else{
        //try to make an educated guess about what the user wants to see
        $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    }
    //store current language in cookie
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
    $langIsoCode = $lang.'_'.strtoupper($lang);
    return $langIsoCode;
}
```